# To get the same id in firebase auth and realtime database

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have done the firebase auth and to save the same data in the firebase database. As shown in the image below, I want the same id which is created while login to get display on the database. I should get the same id if the login is successful.

```
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { email: '', password: '', error: 
 '',user:'',confirmpassword:'' };
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }
 static navigationOptions = {
 title: 'Login',
 };
 state = { loggedIn: null };
 handleChange(e) {
 this.setState({
  email: e.nativeEvent.text,
  password: e.nativeEvent.textpassword,
  user: e.nativeEvent.textuser,
  confirmpassword: e.nativeEvent.textconfirmpassword,

  });
  }
 handleSubmit(email,password,user) {
 db.ref('sevenup-a1db1/').push({
     email:this.state.email,
      password:this.state.password,
      user:''

  }).then((data)=>{
      console.log('data ' , data)
      Alert.alert(
      'Item saved successfully'
       );
  }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log('error ' , error)
  })
 this.setState({ email, password,user });
  }
```

The above code is for saving the data in the firebase database.

```
  componentDidMount() {
   let config = {
   apiKey: "AIzaSyDPVoCjlIlLj1xrgros7hPjF8kkqsD4bSM",
   authDomain: "sevenup-a1db1.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://sevenup-a1db1.firebaseio.com",
   projectId:"sevenup-a1db1",
   storageBucket: "sevenup-a1db1.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId:  "144328588028",
   appId: "1:144328588028:web:2e5addaf8b3e83ad"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: true })
    } else {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: false })
    }
   })

   }

   onButtonPress() {
   this.setState({ error: '', loading: true })
   const { email, password } = this.state;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
  .catch(() => {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
      .catch((error) => {
        let errorCode = error.code
        let errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
          this.onLoginFailure.bind(this)('Weak password!')
        } else {
          this.onLoginFailure.bind(this)(errorMessage)
        }
      });
  });
  }
```

The above code is for saving the data in firebase auth 
I want that after successful login data should be saved in the database successfully. The same id should be displayed in the firebase database which is displayed in firebase auth.

Comment: It looks like your `onLoginSuccess` (which I don't see in the code you shared) is wired up correctly to do this. What is the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but i'm able to see the entries in the firebase auth. i'm getting email and user uid

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i just want that whenever i save the entries the same user uid shows in the firebase database with same entries.

Comment: @Alexander Kuttig can you please help in this i want to link  the firebase auth with the firebase database

Comment: StackOverflow is a very inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll have to tell us what's going on. What's the actual problem when you run this code? Does your `handleSubmit` get called? When you step through it in a debugger, does each line do what you expect it to do? Is there any error message in the JavaScript console.

Comment: i resolved the error anod it is working correctly i was calling in a wrong fonction

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks for the update.